# How can I place a large number of pixels of a certain intensity on a picture?

Tags: image, image-processing, pixel

So, let's say I have a matrix that contains the x and y position aswell as the corresponding intensity of a large number of pixels. I would like to place those pixels one by one, to a specific location.

I've tried using a for loop in combination with the 'image' function (which allows me to place my pixel like that : image(x,y,intensity).). It works but it takes A VERY VERY VERY LONG TIME aswell as a huge spike in memory usage. I need to find an alternative way to make it work.

Is there another way (or another function) that can specifically place a pixel on a certain position, and repeat that process for every pixel ?

Comment: just use numpy. numpy indexing can do this. it's described in all the tutorials.

Comment: Please share an image as an example